# Recursive search, copy and rename of jpg files to parent folder name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've been trying to figure out how to do this with a mixture of different batch commands (copy, forfiles), but i can't figure out one that's just right, doing the copy, renaming and taking into account the directory location.

I have a directory structure of varying levels, which contain many files, however they mostly all have a "folder.jpg".

Something similar to:

- parent\child1\folder.jpg
- parent\child2\folder.jpg
- parent\child3\child4\folder.jpg
- parent\child3\child5\folder.jpg

I would like to scan this, and for any file found called "folder.jpg", make a copy, and rename it to "child1-img.jpg".  I would then see in my structure:

- parent\child1\folder.jpg
- parent\child1\child1-img.jpg
- parent\child2\folder.jpg
- parent\child2\child2-img.jpg
- parent\child3\child4\folder.jpg
- parent\child3\child4\child4-img.jpg
- parent\child3\child5\folder.jpg
- parent\child3\child5\child5-img.jpg

A batch script, that i can run from the directory and only affect sub-directories would be perfect.

Many thanks for any guidance you can give, and please let me know if i've omitted any vital details.

**EDIT**

@paul

Hi Paul, it seems to go through wanting to create a file with each part of the folder names?  I've got a log output below.  Am i reading this right?

```
  START LOOP
  COPY "C:\Users\Mikey\Desktop\blah\New Folder\A Test Folder\Second Test Folder\
folder.jpg" "C:\Users\Mikey\Desktop\blah\New Folder\A Test Folder\Second Test Fo
lder\New-img.jpg"
  END LOOP
Press any key to continue . . .
  COPY "C:\Users\Mikey\Desktop\blah\New Folder\A Test Folder\Second Test Folder\
folder.jpg" "C:\Users\Mikey\Desktop\blah\New Folder\A Test Folder\Second Test Fo
lder\A-img.jpg"
  END LOOP
Press any key to continue . . .
  COPY "C:\Users\Mikey\Desktop\blah\New Folder\A Test Folder\Second Test Folder\
folder.jpg" "C:\Users\Mikey\Desktop\blah\New Folder\A Test Folder\Second Test Fo
lder\Test-img.jpg"
  END LOOP
Press any key to continue . . .
  COPY "C:\Users\Mikey\Desktop\blah\New Folder\A Test Folder\Second Test Folder\
folder.jpg" "C:\Users\Mikey\Desktop\blah\New Folder\A Test Folder\Second Test Fo
lder\Second-img.jpg"
  END LOOP
Press any key to continue . . .
  COPY "C:\Users\Mikey\Desktop\blah\New Folder\A Test Folder\Second Test Folder\
folder.jpg" "C:\Users\Mikey\Desktop\blah\New Folder\A Test Folder\Second Test Fo
lder\Test-img.jpg"
  END LOOP
Press any key to continue . . .
  COPY "C:\Users\Mikey\Desktop\blah\New Folder\A Test Folder\Second Test Folder\
folder.jpg" "C:\Users\Mikey\Desktop\blah\New Folder\A Test Folder\Second Test Fo
lder\Folder-img.jpg"
  END LOOP
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what was wrong with the results? This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Sure, sorry.  So I have this:
forfiles /S /M folder.jpg /C "cmd /c copy @path img.jpg"

That I can run from a batch, and it creates the copy of the file in each folder where necessary, but it will be called "img.jpg".  I cant find a command in forfiles that pulls out just the name of the directory above.
Is forfiles the way to go?

Comment: @Mikey I updated the missing quotes, it should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified from my namesake that handle with space in name :)

```vb
@echo off
SETLOCAL
GOTO START

:START
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%D in (`dir /s /b folder.jpg`) DO (
    SET "DIRPATH=%%~dpD"
    SET "FILEPATH=%%~D"
    SET "FILENAME=%%~nD"
    ECHO:
    ECHO   START LOOP
    IF "!DIRPATH:~-1!" EQU "\" (
        SET "DIRPATH=!DIRPATH:~0,-1!"
    )

    FOR %%F IN ("!DIRPATH!") DO (
        SET "PICDIR=%%~nxF"
        ECHO   COPY "!FILEPATH!" "!DIRPATH!\!PICDIR!-img.jpg"
        ECHO   END LOOP
        PAUSE
    )
)
EXIT /B 0
```

**NOTE:** If you are satisfied, remove every lines that contain `echo` or `pause`, except one which contains `COPY` where only remove `echo` and not the line.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't work out how I was meant to respond with meaningful information in here, as there is a character limit.  I have added an edit to the original question regarding this.
I think it's getting confused with the folder name spacing?

Comment: That sir, worked rather splendidly :)
I did quite a bit of testing on my fake dataset, and just now ran the script on the actual folder structure.  The output looks good for the 30 odd folders i've checked so far.  Just looking for those weird edge cases, but hopefully all is good.
Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @Mikey I'm glad it satisfies you. But all thanks go to my namesake, he does most of the work.

Comment: Yeah, that is awfully confusing.  Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

== directory structure before running script

```
C:>dir /s /b /a-d
C:\Users\pwatson\test\parent\chi ld3\child4\folder.jpg
C:\Users\pwatson\test\parent\chi ld3\child5\folder.jpg
C:\Users\pwatson\test\parent\child1\folder.jpg
C:\Users\pwatson\test\parent\child2\folder.jpg
```

== the script

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%d in (`dir /s /b folder.jpg`) DO (
    SET DIRPATH=%%~dpd
    IF "!DIRPATH:~-1!" EQU "\" (
        SET DIRPATH=!DIRPATH:~0,-1!
    )

    FOR %%f IN ("!DIRPATH!") DO (
        SET PICDIR=%%~nxf
        COPY "%%d" "!DIRPATH!\!PICDIR!-img.jpg"
    )
)

EXIT /B 0
```

== directory structure after running the script

```
C:>dir /s /b /a-d
C:\Users\pwatson\test\parent\chi ld3\child4\child4-img.jpg
C:\Users\pwatson\test\parent\chi ld3\child4\folder.jpg
C:\Users\pwatson\test\parent\chi ld3\child5\child5-img.jpg
C:\Users\pwatson\test\parent\chi ld3\child5\folder.jpg
C:\Users\pwatson\test\parent\child1\child1-img.jpg
C:\Users\pwatson\test\parent\child1\folder.jpg
C:\Users\pwatson\test\parent\child2\child2-img.jpg
C:\Users\pwatson\test\parent\child2\folder.jpg
```

Comment: Hi Paul.  The script didn't make any changes with a test dataset i created. I've gone through the log and I can see that spaces in folder names cause it problems.
There is a mix bag of folder structure, many of which contain spaces in the name.
Is it possible to modify the script to handle spaces?